# mockk, How to use mockk to stub a base class protected function on an instance of derived class

Tags: mockk

Having base class:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseNotification<T: Any> {

    protected abstract fun convertToJson(message: T): JSONObject?

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Throws(JSONException::class)
        protected fun convertMapToJson(dataMap: Map<String, String>): JSONObject {
            val result = JSONObject()
            for ((key, value) in dataMap) {
                result.put(key, value)
            }
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

and derived class:

```kotlin
class DerivedNotification private constructor() : BaseNotification<Intent>() {

    @VisibleForTesting
    internal fun doConvertJson(message: Intent) : JSONObject? = convertToJson(message)

    fun getMap(bundle: Intent): MutableMap<String, String> {
        val bundleToMap: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        for (key in bundle.keySet()) {
            val value = bundle.getString(key)
            if (value != null) {
                bundleToMap[key] = value
            }
        }
        return bundleToMap
    }

    override fun convertToJson(message: Intent): JSONObject? {
        val bundleToMap: MutableMap<String, String> = getMap(message)
        var jsonObject: JSONObject? = null
        jsonObject = try {
            convertMapToJson(bundleToMap)
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            return null
        }
        return jsonObject
    }
}
```

and the test:

```kotlin
@Test
fun test_convertToJson() {
        val derivedNotification = spyk(DerivedNotification())
        every { derivedNotification.getMap(any()) } returns mapWithData

        val intentMock = mockk<Intent>(relaxed = true)

        // Mock the doConvertMapToJson method to throw a JSONException
        every { derivedNotification.convertMapToJson(any()) } throws JSONException("+++ !!! exp")
        //test
        val jsonObj = derivedNotification.doConvertJson(intentMock)
        // verify
        assertNull(jsonObj)
        
    }
```

but since the "convertMapToJson" is a protected function in base class, it does not compile.

How to use mockk to stub a base class protected function?